# Linux Kernel. Where the list of PMUs (Performanse Monitor Unit) for ARM processor is being initialized?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am fixing the bug where the armv8_pmuv3 device is being registered twice in sysfs filesystem. I.e. I receive the error message like this: "sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/armv8_pmuv3'" and "kobject_add_internal failed for armv8_pmuv3 with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.". I discovered that this device appears twice in the list of PMUs. I found this list in the kernel/events/core.c file. This list is named pmus. But I cannot find where and how this list is being filled and where the armv8_pmuv3 device was added to it. So I could avoid double registration the armv8_pmuv3 in this list. Can anyone help me to find where pmus list is being filled and where the armv8_pmuv3 is being added?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may be that you have double devices in the Device Tree or so. The kernel enumerates devices and binds the drivers. If you have more than one device and a driver isn't written in a way to support this, you will have that kind of traceback.

Comment: We need more information on the structure of the DT.  There is a mode where u-boot can create it and you can have another mode where it is attached to the image.  If you use 'u-boot', it can append things to the DT.  The idea is that u-boot can run on several boards, and identify them to provide information to the running Linux system.  For a static board image, you can bundle the DT.  I expect it is u-boot that might be adding it.  What does the CPU do before `start_kernel()`?

Comment: Hi, guys. Thanks a lot for your advice. The reason was in the Device Thee. The redundant item with armv8-pmuv3 was added in there. I removed all information about armv8-pmuv3 from the Device Tree and the error message disappeared. Now armv8_pmuv3 registers once. Probably the bootloader adds the armv8_pmuv3 device into the list of devices.